# How to add multiple duplicate-linked legs to a single armature?

Tags: armature, bones, linked-data

I want to make a quadruped insect robot. Each leg will be exactly the same. They will have three regular bones and an Inverse Kinematics bone at the end. I want to connect them to a single body/spine bone using the "Make Parent > Keep Offset" relationship, so that I can just move the spine to make a crouching pose, twist the body, etc.

Here's a proof-of-concept armature:

http://lab.narf.pl/tmp/2017-01-06-blender-legs.gif

As I mentioned, legs will be exactly the same, but I'm sure they will change quite a bit in the process of making the robot. My idea was to model a single leg, create an armature for it and duplicate them with <kbd>ALT+D</kbd> ("Duplicate Linked"), so that I can make edits in one place. It works fine (I can pose legs independently) until I try to connect legs to the spine (a separate armature).

I've tried a few things but they don't give the desired effect:

1. When I join the spine's armature with one leg's armature, all legs get a separate spine.
2. When I first unlink one leg's armature (by pressing <kbd>U</kbd>: "Make Single User > Object & Data"), I can join it with the spine and it works OK, but when I repeat it for the second leg, its mesh gets disconnected from the armature.

How can I achieve the result from the proof-of-concept GIF and reuse a single editable leg object at the same time?

Here's the [`.blend` file](http://lab.narf.pl/tmp/2017-01-06-blender-legs.blend) I experimented on:

- 1st layer: Proof-of-concept armature from the GIF.
- 2nd layer: A leg mesh and armature. This is what I want to modify during development.
- 3rd layer: A spine and duplicate-linked objects from the second layer. Bottom left leg is unlinked (<kbd>U</kbd>) and joined with the spine. Bottom right leg is unlinked but not yet joined.

Comment: Could you please upload your .blend file?

Comment: @Tak yes, I've just added [a link](http://lab.narf.pl/tmp/2017-01-06-blender-legs.blend) at the end of the description. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, and from where did you get this gif? could you provide the .blend file of it as well or a link to where you found it?

Comment: @Tak sorry, I should've described what's in the `.blend` file. The GIF is a capture of the proof-of-concept armature from the first layer. On the second layer there's a leg mesh and armature. On the third layer there's a spine and duplicate-linked objects from the second layer. Bottom left leg is unlinked (<kbd>U</kbd>) and joined with the spine. Bottom right leg is unlinked but not yet joined.

Comment: so you want the third layer to act like the first layer, right?

Comment: @Tak yes, but I want the layer three meshes to be linked to the original model from the second layer, so that I can make mesh changes only on one leg and see them on all four legs.